# PyQT Threading and Socketing safely, and catching multiple signals

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt, signals, qthread

I'm writing some code currently that uses standard threads, a Queue, QThreads in pyqt, and sockets.
Basically I open a socket server, and receive data from other programs. I have a few questions here.

1. My program seems to hang upon closing even if I try to kill my threads properly. The only way to avoid this is to set a particular thread as a daemon. What I was doing to kill it, was using a member(
   `self._terminate = threading.Event()`) which I would set in my `closeEvent()` of my GUI.
   My thread would check constantly for this termination and return if it exists.
   My socket would also be closed - child connections would have `shutdown()` called on them, and the main server would have some fake data sent through to push the listen loop on the thread, which would also terminate.

All of this, as I mentioned, happened in the `closeEvent()` of my GUI, but when I had it set up this way, it would hang on exit. The program would *hide* but the shell would remain active, and it wasn't dead. By setting the thread that holds the server socket to a daemon, everything closed okay.

This is safe to do, since I am not writing any contents to a file, or reading from a file, correct?

2. My second part of the question, is I have a `QThread` set up to collect any incoming data form my PriorityQueue and send signals to the GUI as needed. It sends all available data each time it does a check, something roughly like:

-

```
class DataCollector(QtCore.QThread):
    dataSig = QtCore.SIGNAL('data')

    def __init__(self, q):
        super(DataCollector, self).__init__(None)

        self.check_time = 5
        self.scan_time = 0.2
        self.last_check = time.time() - self.check_time
        self.queue = q
        self._terminate = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self._terminate:
                return

            time.sleep(self.scan_time)

            if time.time() > self.last_check + self.check_time:
                while self.queue.empty is False:
                    data = self.queue.get()
                    self.emit(self.dataSig, data)
```

My main UI would then catch these signals, and in my tests - add them to a last widget.

In my tests, once in a while, the test data would get combined into one line - for instance if my Queue contained

- test
- test again
- test MORE

and i emitted these signals quickly until the queue was empty, once in a while my list widget would have a double entry such as:

- test
- test again
- test MORE
- test
- test again
- test MORE
- test
- test againtest More   ******

Is this because I'm firing them out too fast? What might cause that, and what are some possible fixes?

Thanks for any and all input!

Comment: I think it will be difficult to answer 1) without seeing the relevant code of the `closeEvent()` method and the thread. For 2), I would suggest trying to switch to [new style signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) in your `QThread` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Ill post the closeEvent tomorrow - and yeah ill try the new signal and slots system and see if that's it, but i have a feeling its related to firing too many at once from the same thread. - thnks

Comment: @Aboogie this is not my question, I just edited it to improve the content. You'll need to ask Alex.

Comment: @AlexAnders hey , do you mind, sharing some of this code, I am trying to send data continuously in the background using a gui, but i having some trouble understanding and implementing a thread client socket that continuously sends new data in the background thats being changed in the first thread of the gui.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it has nothing to do with the speed of the signal, since QT internally handles these in a queue-type fashion.
What I think is happening, is that you are under the impression that when you call `send` or `sendall` from a socket, all the data is sent as one packet, and when you `recv(bytes)`, it will receive the full packets sent one at a time.

This is not the case. The data is sent in a stream like fashion, so you can end up with chunks, or combined results. There are 2 ways around this:

1. Send some data at the start of each packet saying how long, in bytes, the following data is, and then `recv` that much.
2. Send your data with a delimiter, for example, if your delimiter is `|!|`, the data sent would be: `test|!|`, `testAgain|!|`, `testMore|!|`. Then you handle this on your receiving thread. For instance, the stream may come through the first time as: `test|!|testA`, followed by `gain|!|testMore|!|`
   the second time.

In your thread you can handle splitting the received data by the given delimiter, and holding onto unfinished chunks until the next delimiter is found.